# Using Context Isolation in Electron - how do I get modules working?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm learning Electron and trying to write an app using best practices. I started a new project using Electron Forge with the webpack template. I'm trying to implement context isolation with preload.js. For reference, I am using the approach outlined here: https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md

Enabling contextIsolation keeps breaking my code and the "solutions" I usually find while searching around typically involve setting nodeIntegration to true, which is what we're trying to avoid!

---

My approach has been to comment out virtually all non-boilerplate code and try to introduce things one at a time.

1. I had an initial issue at app launch with "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I searched for a long time until I came across a post suggesting to change the `module.exports` `target` in webpack.renderer.config.js from `electron-renderer` to `web`. That did clear the error and allow my renderer script to do some basic functions, but I have no idea why it worked or if it's a good thing to do.
2. Path problems - in my renderer, I have an event listener which handles a button event and gets a filepath back from a selected file in a dialog box. I want to use `path` to get the basename, but I can't import it directly to renderer. How do I work around this? *Figured this out! Basically if you need to access a Node or Electron module method that's only available in main, you put a new method in contextBridge that points to an ipcMain method in main.js. So, for me, I want to invoke since I'm sending a file path and receiving a file name:*

```
//in preload -> contextBridge
    basename: (path) => {
            return ipcRenderer.invoke("basename", path);
//in main
    ipcMain.handle('basename', async (event, args) => {
      let fileName = path.basename(args);
      return fileName;
});
//in renderer
    filename = await window.api.basename(selectedFile);
```

3. Module problems - I want to be able to run a python script. I have a simple python module which uses `python-shell`, but if I attempt to import it with context isolation, I get a "require is not defined" error.

I feel like I'm just not quite understanding how to work with context isolation enabled and it's a difficult issue to get relevant search results on. Maybe it has something to do with my configs? Can I get some help? Relevant code below:

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } = require('electron');
import * as path from 'path';

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

let win;

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
    },
  });

  win.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  win.webContents.openDevTools();
};

//typical stuff
```

renderer.js

```
import * as pyScripts from './pyscripts.js';

//other code is fine so far
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        },
        invoke: (channel, data) => {
            let validChannels = ["toFromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

pyscripts.js

```
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';

function test(){
    PythonShell.runString('x=1+1;print(x)', null).then(messages=>{
        console.log('finished');
      });
}

export {
    test
};
```